# How do I get these toggles in my notification bar?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, notification-bar

I was reading an article talking about the [Galaxy Nexus vs. the Galaxy SIII](http://www.androidauthority.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-vs-samsung-galaxy-nexus-video-96114/), and ended up buying a Nexus (was a steal, and I knew it was getting JB).

Anyway, I've recently updated it to Jellybean, but I realised that I didn't have something that was showing in the article - [the toggles they showed in the Notification bar (in the right hand image)](http://1.androidauthority.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/statusbar.jpeg).

Are these provided in the standard ROM, by an app, or in a custom ROM? I can't seem to find them.

Comment: I'd have a shot at guessing it's on a custom ROM. If you're using AOKP, these toggle settings are located inside **ROM Control**.

Comment: You're looking for exactly this design -- or just the functionality of those toggles?

Comment: @Izzy In the long run, I just want GPS, WiFi and Data connection toggles that fit the ICS/Jellybean notification theme nicely.

Comment: So in the short run, you might want to take a look at Elixier2 -- which at least could place *some* toggles there (so you'd have the functionality).

Comment: So the long-term would be learn to write my own?

Comment: That would require modifying the SystemUI component of the framework which controls the status bar/pull down notifications

Comment: Something tells me that modifying that component isn't going to happen without flashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These toggles aren't part of Android. Third party ROMs like CyanogenMod and MIUI, and certain skins that Hardware manufacturers put on Android include that.

If you want to have this functionality on a Nexus running stock Android you might want to try these two applications, I have used them both, and they are quite stable and useful.

Power Toggles : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc

More Quickly Panel: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mabware.android.MoreQuicklyPanel

Comment: Looks like Power Toggles is SLIGHTLY off the theming I'm after, but otherwise it's perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The notification toggles are not part of standard Android OS (ICS, Jelly Bean, etc.)  Some 3rd-party apps give this feature, although they are usually not very stable.  Custom ROMs like CyanogenMod and AOKP provide this functionality as part of system settings.

Comment: I'm a developer, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around Android modifications. I did a custom flash to install Jellybean (local provider is slow off the mark), but otherwise I know nothing. Is there a good guide I can visit to work out which ROM I should look at? Do any of them do Jellybean yet?

Comment: The best (arguably) source for user guides and ROMs is xda-developers forums: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1336

Answer (score 0):

I know this question question was already solved, but I have found another app that does exactly what you need: [SwitchPro Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=alei.switchpro). Maybe other users will be more comfortable using this app. You can fully customize as you want it to be. I am using it for some time now, and I really love it

Answer (score -2):

Another app I would highly recommend is Notification Toggle.

Comment: Please add a link to the app